# How to create activities with current user logged in using zoho crm

Tags: zoho

**Hi,
I am practice with Zoho CRM for doing some third party integration but I am facing problem when I logged-in with new user and I am going to create activity for calls record but when I checked activity created with CEO details (Like parent details user id) not with current user logged in.
If any suggestion Please let me know.**

Comment: Are you trying to create call activity using deluge or external tool ?

Answer (score 0):

By default, all records created by automations will be owned by the admin user. In the payload to create records, pass the key `Owner` with value `zoho.loginuserid`. This would set the activity owner as the user logged in.